# PHP curl redirection not working

Tags: php, curl

With this code redirection only works with some sites, and with some don't:

```
    $url = "http://slayradio.org";
    $ch = curl_init();  //  Initiate curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  // Set the url
    $html = curl_exec($ch);  // Execute
    curl_close($ch);  // Closing
    if(is_null($html) || empty($html)) {
        die("Could not read remote url: $url");
    }
    print("loads ok");
```

However this command-line actually outputs the html page:

```
curl -s -L "http://slayradio.org"
```

I am sure the site is fully connectable from where the server is running.
In fact if i change the url to "http://www.slayradio.org/home.php" it actually works!

phpinfo() on the server reports that cURL version is 7.47.1.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code myself, and it seems to work for me

Comment: then i guess the issue is a curl-related bug, any workaround i may try?